# Convert binary signal to int number

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gpio, wiringpi

I'm trying to convert the input of the GPIOs of a raspberry pi to a int.
So I have five digital inputs and want to read the inputs. Once i got the values I store them in an array. The next thing would be to convert the content of the array to a int number.

So here's my code:

```
int a = digitalRead(PIN_16);
int b = digitalRead(PIN_18);
int c = digitalRead(PIN_22);
int d = digitalRead(PIN_24);
int e = digitalRead(PIN_26);

int array[5];

array[0]=a;
array[1]=b;
array[2]=c;
array[3]=d;
array[4]=e;
```

To convert the content of the array to a number I would youse if conditions to see if the first input is 1 or 0. If its 1 I a 1, else 0. And so on ... .

My question now is if there's a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: What should the number be? (for instance what should the number be if only pin16 is high)

Comment: Multiply each value by a different power of 2 (or left-shift them by different amounts) and add them together (or alternatively, bit-wise-OR them together). For example `value = (a << 0) | (b << 1) | (c << 2) | (d << 3) | (e << 4);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just "shift" bits into the appropriate positions in the number:

```
unsigned int number = 0;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    number |= a[i] << i;
}
```

This will work in case `digitalRead` is returning `0` or `1` only. In case it returns `0` or a `non-zero` values we will need to check it against zero instead:

```
unsigned int number = 0;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    number |= (a[i] != 0) << i;  //  (a[i] != 0) will have a value of `1` for any non-zero `a[i]`
}
```

or even more idiomatic trick:

```
number |= !!a[i] << i;
```

This is a double logical negation. The first one will turn any non-zero into `0`, the second will turn the `0` into `1`.

Comment: This only works if `digitalRead` returns a 1 when the pin is high. I've seen implementations where `digitalRead` already returns a bitset and you could call the function like: `digitalRead(PIN1 | PIN2 | PIN5);` and i've also seen implementations where it does `return ~0;` if a pin is high...

Comment: @Lanting Yeah, that was my assumption. Will add some more to address this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks your function worked quite fine on a raspberry. Just for information: The digitalread() function in wiringpi.h returns 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with bitwise operations:

```
result = array[4]<<4 | array[3]<<3 | array[2]<<2 | array[1]<<1 | array[0]
```